# uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'touppercase' of undefined Observable._subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile

I have an issue. I develop mobile app with ionic framework. It's movie app. I found one example on github and tried to implement some functions and design into my project.

I have the page 'Store'. When I start the project I get the error

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined at Observable._subscribe

It come from ngOnInit function, but I can't see what is wrong. I just recently started to learn mobile development with ionic framework, ts and angular. I will be glad for any help.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service';
import { MovieDetailsPage } from '../movie-details/movie-details';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-store',
  templateUrl: 'store.html'
})
 export class StorePage {

  movies: Array<any>;

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private movieService: 
 MovieService) {

     }

     ngOnInit(){
        this.movieService.send('getMovies').subscribe(a => {
            console.log(a);
            this.movies = a.results.map(b => {
                return {
                    id: b.id,
                    title: b.title,
                    image: b.poster_path,
                    overview: b.overview,
                    rating: b.vote_average
                }
            })
        });
     }

     searchMovieDB(event, key) {
         if(event.target.value.length > 2) {
             this.movieService.searchMovies(event.target.value).subscribe(
                 data => {
                     this.movies = data.results; 
                     console.log(data);
                 },
                 err => {
                     console.log(err);
                 },
                 () => console.log('Movie Search Complete')
              );
         }
     } 

     itemTapped(event, movie) {
         //console.log(movie);
         this.movieService.send('getSingleMovie', movie.id).subscribe(data 
  => console.log(data));  
         this.navCtrl.push(MovieDetailsPage, {
             movie: movie
         });
     }

 }
```

Here is 'MovieService' which I use to create api requests:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestMethod, Request} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {

    }

    searchMovies(movieName) {
        var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=&query=' + 
encodeURI(movieName) + '&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

        var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
        return response;
    }

    send(name, id?, item?) {

                let url: string,
                    body: any,
                    api_key: string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

                if(name == 'getMovies')
                    url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'?
api_key=' + api_key;
                else if (name == 'getMoviesByPage')
                    url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?
api_key='+api_key+'&page=' + id;
                else if (name == 'getSingleMovie')
                    url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'?
api_key=' + api_key;
                else if (name == 'getVideo')
                    url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'/videos?
api_key=' + api_key;
                else if (name == 'getImages')
                    url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'/images?
api_key=' + api_key;


                let options = {
                    url: url,
                    body: null
                };

                if (item) {
                    body = typeof item === 'string' ? item : 
 JSON.stringify(item);
                    options.body = body;
                }


                return this.http.request(new Request(options))
                    .map(res => res.json())

            }
}
```

Comment: I think that piece of code is not the affected one. There is no call to `toUppderCase` there.

Comment: Did you get smth else in your console? Did you try to temporarily remove this subscribe?

Comment: where did you use `toUpperCase`? can you please add that snippet as well?

Comment: added full ts code of page and service. I'm not using 'toUpperCase' and I don't know why it appears

Comment: Can you add code of `store.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you are using `Request` (which is deprecated along with `Http` by the way). You would want to just make get request, nothing else needed really. I see some problems in your code, for example when getting a single movie based on id, your app would throw an error at the mapping inside subscribe, since the data you would get back from fetching one movie would just return an object, not an array. So you need to rethink that!

But here's a sample with getting one movie based on id:

```
send(name, id?, item?) {
  let url: string,
  api_key: string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  if (name == 'getMovies') 
    url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=' + api_key

  return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.movieService.send('getMovies').subscribe(a => {
    this.movies = a // will not be an array in this case, just an object! 
  });
}
```

Comment: DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qu29r8?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts I'll just leave the demo as a comment, to be able to fully delete it, since I used your api key (which you shouldn't share in most cases) :)

Comment: Thank you!
I see the difference now. 
I changed 'request' to 'get' (as you said) and it works well.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :)